# How to correct this Procedure

Tags: oracle

I get an error "ORA-06512" for the following procedure. Please rectify and correct me:

```
DROP TRIGGER XYZ.CHECK_DATE_TIME;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER XYZ.CHECK_DATE_TIME
BEFORE INSERT ON RFID.ATTENDANCE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
TMPVAR NUMBER;
BEGIN
  -------------------------------------
IF SECURITY.F_WS_USER() THEN
RETURN;
END IF;
IF :NEW.CHECK_TIME < (SYSDATE - 10)
OR :NEW.CHECK_TIME > (SYSDATE + ((1 / 24) / 60) * 10) THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,
'Unable to save machine data in RFID.ATTENDANCE as it is older than 5 days ');
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Compile time or run time?

Comment: In either case, you should get a line number on where the error is occurring

Comment: Is that a "procedure" or a "trigger"? Or do you think the two are one and the same?

Comment: some possible things : 1. SECURITY.F_WS_USER() can throw ORA 06512 error, 2. you try to insert null on check_time

Comment: Let me correct, this is a trigger. I am getting this error at run time! and Error occurs at Line No. 10

Comment: Line 10 seems to point to the function call. What is `F_WS_USER()`? Does it return a Boolean value?

Comment: @mathguy Yes this is a Function call and it returns Boolean Value.

Comment: So, did you debug that function?